# Getting list of names of Azure blob files in a container?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-blob-storage

I need to list names of Azure Blob file names. Currently I m able to list all files with URL but I just need list of names. I want to avoid parsing names. Can you please see my below code and guide:

```
CloudStorageAccount backupStorageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(blobConectionString);

var backupBlobClient = backupStorageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
var backupContainer = backupBlobClient.GetContainerReference(container);

var list = backupContainer.ListBlobs();
```

Comment: Does your blob container contain just block blobs? If that's the case, then you could simply do something like: `List<string> blobNames = list.Select(b => (b as CloudBlockBlob).Name);`.

Answer (score 36):

If you're using **Windows Azure Storage 4.3.0**, try this code.

```
List<string> blobNames = list.OfType<CloudBlockBlob>().Select(b => b.Name).ToList();
```

Comment: We can get some additional info like Size, Modified date and more.
Refer my answer at bottom.

Comment: What is `list`?

Comment: `list` is found in askers post above.

Comment: Answer outdated - ListBlobs not available anymore - see this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/59474285/10133085

Answer (score 16):

Here is one more way to get this done:

```
CloudStorageAccount backupStorageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(blobConectionString);

var backupBlobClient = backupStorageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
var backupContainer = backupBlobClient.GetContainerReference(container);

// useFlatBlobListing is true to ensure loading all files in
// virtual blob sub-folders as a plain list
var list = backupContainer.ListBlobs(useFlatBlobListing: true);
var listOfFileNames = new List<string>();

foreach (var blob in blobs) {
  var blobFileName = blob.Uri.Segments.Last();
  listOfFileNames.Add(blobFileName); 
}

return listOfFileNames;
```

Source: [How to load list of Azure blob files recursively?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30269417/how-to-load-list-of-azure-blob-files-recursively)

Comment: I think `list` should be updated to `blobs`. i.e. `var blobs = backupContainer.ListBlobs(useFlatBlobListing: true);`

Answer (score 15):

We can get some additional info like **Size, Modified date** and **Name**.

```
CloudStorageAccount backupStorageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(YOUR_CON_STRING);

var backupBlobClient = backupStorageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
var backupContainer = backupBlobClient.GetContainerReference("CONTAINER");


var blobs = backupContainer.ListBlobs().OfType<CloudBlockBlob>().ToList();

foreach (var blob in blobs)
{
    string bName = blob.Name;
    long bSize = blob.Properties.Length;
    string bModifiedOn = blob.Properties.LastModified.ToString();        
}
```

Also you can **download** a specific file by Name.

```
 // Download file by Name
 string fileName = "Your_file_name";
 CloudBlockBlob blobFile = backupContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(fileName);
 blobFile.DownloadToFile(@"d:\"+ fileName, System.IO.FileMode.Create);
```

Answer (score 12):

Full answer with details.

```
        // Parse the connection string and return a reference to the storage account.
        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("AzureBlobConnectionString"));

        CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

        // Retrieve reference to a previously created container.
        CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("container_name");

        // Retrieve reference to a blob named "test.csv"
        CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("BlobName.tex");

        //Gets List of Blobs
        var list = container.ListBlobs();
        List<string> blobNames = list.OfType<CloudBlockBlob>().Select(b => b.Name).ToList();
```

Comment: I was facing problems regarding blobs with a space in its name. I was using the absolute uri and it wasn't serving my purpose. This answer solved the problem for me.

Comment: I am glad I could help.

Answer (score 12):

This works with **WindowsAzure.Storage 9.3.3**.

```
CloudBlobClient cloudBlobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
var cloudBlobContainer = cloudBlobClient.GetContainerReference(containerName);

var blobResultSegment = await cloudBlobContainer.ListBlobsSegmentedAsync(continuationToken);
var blobs = blobResultSegment.Results.Select(i => i.Uri.Segments.Last()).ToList();
```

Comment: What is `continuationToken`??

Comment: `BlobContinuationToken continuationToken = null;`

Comment: @PetraStručić please provide some information, the comment you gave is not helpful!

Comment: @Peter please provide some information, the comment you gave is not helpful!

On a more serious note, I think my comment is self-explanatory regarding the context of this whole thread, but can you ask a specific question? I would like to improve my comment if possible.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by just commenting a line of code without writing what it's for... "The property is null if there are no more items to fetch" would have been motch more helpful and clear.

Comment: I focused on the scope of the original question, but sure.

Since getting all blobs can be a heavy operation to do, it's good to granulate it in smaller chunks with `maxResults` parameter. `ContinuationToken` tracks the number of records left for listing. In this concrete code example of mine, its potential is not used.

Here's an example of its use:

`do
    {
        var response = await ListBlobsSegmentedAsync(continuationToken);
        continuationToken = response.ContinuationToken;
        results.AddRange(response.Results);
    }
    while (continuationToken != null);`

Comment: how would you iterate through all containers and all the blobs in those containers?

Answer (score 8):

##### Update:

Getting list of names of Azure blob files with **Azure.Storage.Blobs v12** - Package

```
var storageConnectionString = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=...........=core.windows.net";
var blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(storageConnectionString);

//get container
var container = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient("container_name");

List<string> blobNames = new List<string>();

//Enumerating the blobs may make multiple requests to the service while fetching all the values
//Blobs are ordered lexicographically by name
//if you want metadata set BlobTraits - BlobTraits.Metadata
var blobs = container.GetBlobsAsync(BlobTraits.None, BlobStates.None);
await foreach (var blob in blobs)
{
    blobNames.Add(blob.Name);
}
```

There are more option and example you can find it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blobs-list?tabs=dotnet).

This is the [link](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.Storage.Blobs) to the nuget package.

Answer (score 6):

The `ListBlobs` method doesn't appear to exist anymore. Here is an async verison.

```
    public static async Task<List<string>> ListBlobNamesAsync(CloudBlobContainer container)
    {
        var blobs = await ListBlobsAsync(container);
        return blobs.Cast<CloudBlockBlob>().Select(b => b.Name).ToList();

        //Alternate version
        //return blobs.Select(b => b.Uri.ToString()).Select(s => s.Substring(s.LastIndexOf('/') + 1)).ToList();
    }

    public static async Task<List<IListBlobItem>> ListBlobsAsync(CloudBlobContainer container)
    {
        BlobContinuationToken continuationToken = null; //start at the beginning
        var results = new List<IListBlobItem>();
        do
        {
            var response = await container.ListBlobsSegmentedAsync(continuationToken);
            continuationToken = response.ContinuationToken;
            results.AddRange(response.Results);
        }

        while (continuationToken != null); //when this is null again, we've reached the end
        return results;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am not setup on Azure yet, but I was wondering, if you know, how fast is listing say, 1000 blob names? I know it depends on several factors, but just a very general estimate would help me. Thanks.

Comment: I don't remember, other than it was fast enough to not annoy me. I only have a few hundred objects, but I can't imagine you'll run into any problems with a thousand.

Answer (score 2):

You can access the `BlobProperties` to get the name:

```
foreach (object o in list)
{
    BlobProperties bp = o as BlobProperties;
    if (bp != null)
    {
        BlobProperties p = _Container.GetBlobProperties(bp.Name);
        var name = p.Name; // get the name
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks. Can it be done in Lambda/ Linq please ? Also just thinking this way it will call GetBlobProperties function for every blob file right ? Your advice please.

Comment: What is `list`?

Answer (score 2):

```
  CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"));
   CloudFileClient fileClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudFileClient();
    CloudFileShare share = fileClient.GetShareReference(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ShareReference"]);
    if (share.Exists())
    {
          CloudFileDirectory rootDir = share.GetRootDirectoryReference();
          CloudFileDirectory sampleDir = rootDir.GetDirectoryReference("paths");
          if (sampleDir.Exists())
          {
                IEnumerable<IListFileItem> fileList = sampleDir.ListFilesAndDirectories();
                 //CloudFile file = sampleDir.GetFileReference(FileName + ext);
                 //return file;
           }
           return null;
      }
```

From fileList one can get all the files from azure file

Answer (score 0):

We have to use `ListBlobsSegmentedAsync()` method, Then we can find out the blob by the following code :

```
public CloudBlockBlob GetLatestBlobByBlobNamePattern(CloudBlobContainer container, string blobNamePattern) 
        {
            var root = container.GetDirectoryReference(string.Empty);
            var blobsList = root.ListBlobsSegmentedAsync(null);
            blobsList.Wait();
            BlobResultSegment segment = blobsList.Result;
            List<IListBlobItem> list = new List<IListBlobItem>();
            list.AddRange(segment.Results);
            while (segment.ContinuationToken != null)
            {
                var blobs = container.ListBlobsSegmentedAsync(segment.ContinuationToken);
                blobs.Wait();
                segment = blobs.Result;
                list.AddRange(segment.Results);
            }
            var blob = list.Where(x => x.Uri.Segments.Last().Contains(blobNamePattern)).FirstOrDefault();
            return (CloudBlockBlob)blob;
        }
```