# How to load list of Azure blob files recursively?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage

Azure blob files are stored in a plain list without any physical folder structure, but we can create virtual folders where each file's folder path is a part of its name.

It brings out another problem, how to retrieve a list of ALL files in virtual sub-folder, using only that folder's name?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Actually, there's a simpler way to do that and it is available in the library itself. If you look at [`CloudBlobContainer.ListBlobs`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudblobcontainer.listblobs.aspx) method, it accepts two parameters:

1. **prefix**: This is the name of your directory. If it is a nested directory, you will need to specify the full path e.g. myfolder/mysubfolder.
2. **useFlatBlobListing**: Setting this value to `true` will ensure that only blobs are returned (including inside any sub folders inside that directory) and not directories and blobs.

   ```
   var account = new CloudStorageAccount(new StorageCredentials(accountName, accountKey), true);
   var blobClient = account.CreateCloudBlobClient();
   var container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("blob-container-name");
   var blobs = container.ListBlobs(prefix: "container-directory", useFlatBlobListing: true);
   ```

You will get a list of all blobs belonging in the "container-directory" in `blobs` variable.

Comment: that does look much simpler, I'll try it out !! thank you for sharing

Comment: For Java developers out there replace `:` with `=` and the method names should start with a small letter.

Answer (score 15):

This static class `BlobHelper` will load the list of all the blob files in a given blob folder, and all of its sub-folders.

Just call it like this:

```
var blobs = BlobHelper.ListFolderBlobs("blob-container-name", "container-directory");
```

Here is full `BlobHelper` code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob;

// Class to contain list of blob files info
public class BlobFileInfo {
  public string FileName { get; set; }
  public string BlobPath { get; set; }
  public string BlobFilePath { get; set; }
  public IListBlobItem Blob { get; set; }
}
public static class BlobHelper {
// Load blob container
public static CloudBlobContainer GetBlobContainer(string containerName) {
  var storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"));
  var blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
  var container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(containerName);
  return container;
}

// Get recursive list of files
public static IEnumerable<BlobFileInfo> ListFolderBlobs(string containerName, string directoryName) {
  var blobContainer = GetBlobContainer(containerName);
  var blobDirectory = blobContainer.GetDirectoryReference(directoryName);
  var blobInfos = new List<BlobFileInfo>();
  var blobs = blobDirectory.ListBlobs().ToList();
  foreach (var blob in blobs) {
    if (blob is CloudBlockBlob) {
      var blobFileName = blob.Uri.Segments.Last().Replace("%20", " ");
      var blobFilePath = blob.Uri.AbsolutePath.Replace(blob.Container.Uri.AbsolutePath + "/", "").Replace("%20", " ");
      var blobPath = blobFilePath.Replace("/" + blobFileName, "");
      blobInfos.Add(new BlobFileInfo {
        FileName = blobFileName,
        BlobPath = blobPath,
        BlobFilePath = blobFilePath,
        Blob = blob
      });
    }
    if (blob is CloudBlobDirectory) {
      var blobDir = blob.Uri.OriginalString.Replace(blob.Container.Uri.OriginalString + "/", "");
      blobDir = blobDir.Remove(blobDir.Length - 1);
      var subBlobs = ListFolderBlobs(containerName, blobDir);
      blobInfos.AddRange(subBlobs);
    }
  }
  return blobInfos;
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks for this, but what's the accountSlug meant to be? I get an exception there.

Comment: @Craig, I believe that should be `containerName` instead, I got that corrected, it should work now. Also check out this answer, it may have even simplier solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30272025/448816.

Comment: Thanks, got it working. It only lists one directory though. Looking for a full tree, top to bottom, listing. Now trying to convert this to Razor: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/597939/ModelingplusaplusDirectoryplusStructureplusonplusA.
Thanks again.

Comment: Really nice piece of code there. Threw out everything I had an just used this, modifying it a little for my own needs.

Comment: @mikhail-t... very nice methods

Comment: This comment is a goldmine of useful info for folks like me who are getting started working with BlobStorage in .NET. Kudos!

Answer (score 0):

From Gaurav Mantri's answer, here's a simple way to show the files recursively as a hierarchy.

```
public class UriNode
{
    public Uri ThisUri { get; private set; }

    public IEnumerable<UriNode> Children { get; private set; }

    public UriNode(CloudBlobContainer container, Uri thisUri = null)
    {
        ThisUri = thisUri;

        if (ThisUri == null)
        {
            Children = container.ListBlobs().Select(b => new UriNode(container, b.Uri));
            return;
        }

        if (!new Regex(@"\/$").IsMatch(ThisUri.AbsolutePath)) return;

        var prefix = string.Join("/", ThisUri.Segments.Skip(2).Take(ThisUri.Segments.Length - 2));
        Children = container.ListBlobs(prefix).Select(b => new UriNode(container, b.Uri));
    }
}
```

usage:

```
new UriNode(container);
```