# Query a Blob container to retrieve files

Tags: c#, azure-blob-storage

I have some .png files inside a Blob Container, I'm able to retrieve a file by passing the filename as a parameter :

`var blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(System.IO.Path.GetFileName(fileName));`

But I want to query that Blob Container and have a list of all the files that it contains. How would I do that?

```
 public class FilesController : Controller
    {
        private CloudBlobContainer container;
        private CloudStorageAccount storageAccount;
        private CloudBlobClient blobClient;
        private CloudTableClient tableClient;
 public FilesController()
        {
            this.storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(_dbConnection.ConnectionAzure);
            this.storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
            this.blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
            this.container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("public/MyFolder");
            this.tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();
        }

public ActionResult MyMethod(string fileName)
        {
           var blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(System.IO.Path.GetFileName(fileName));
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
var list = container.ListBlobs(useFlatBlobListing: true);
var listOfFileNames = new List<string>();

foreach (var blob in blobs) {
  var blobFileName = blob.Uri.Segments.Last();
  listOfFileNames.Add(blobFileName); 
}

return listOfFileNames;
```

Source: [Getting list of names of Azure blob files in a container?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30314037/1186936)