# How to get the files in an Azure container virtual folder using c#

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage

I've reviewed this:
[Getting list of names of Azure blob files in a container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23485514/getting-list-of-names-of-azure-blob-files-in-a-container)

and this: 
https://feedback.azure.com/forums/287593-logic-apps/suggestions/16252474-list-files-in-folder-on-azure-blob-storage

But I have not found any code examples of how to list the files in a particular virtual folder within a container using c#.  This is as far as I got.  I do not see any way to specify a file path in the ListBlobs ()method.

```
        var blobStorageAccount = GetStorageAccount();
        var blobClient = blobStorageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        var blobContainer = blobClient.GetContainerReference(containerName);
        List<string> blobNames = blobContainer.ListBlobs().OfType<CloudBlockBlob>().Select(b => b.Name).ToList();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no such thing as a subfolder. You have containers containing blobs. You *do* have **virtual** folders, for example

```
/container/virtualfolder/myblob
```

The container name is `container` and the blob name is `virtualfolder/myblob`

You can list all blobs in a virtual folder using the `prefix` parameter (see [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudblobcontainer.listblobs?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=azure-dotnet&viewFallbackFrom=azurestorage-8.1.3#Microsoft_WindowsAzure_Storage_Blob_CloudBlobContainer_ListBlobs_System_String_System_Boolean_Microsoft_WindowsAzure_Storage_Blob_BlobListingDetails_Microsoft_WindowsAzure_Storage_Blob_BlobRequestOptions_Microsoft_WindowsAzure_Storage_OperationContext_)):

```
        var blobStorageAccount = GetStorageAccount();
        var blobClient = blobStorageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        var blobContainer = blobClient.GetContainerReference(containerName);
        List<string> blobNames = blobContainer.ListBlobs(prefix: "virtualfolder").OfType<CloudBlockBlob>().Select(b => b.Name).ToList();
```

Comment: That worked.  Thanks! Is there a built in way to isolate the blob name from the virtual path?  Or, perhaps Path.GetFileName() will work

Comment: Hmm not sure. `Path.GetFileName()` might work, or you can try a `.Split('/').Last()`

Answer (score 2):

`Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob` is deprecated. Using `Azure.Storage.Blob` looks like it would be:

```
List<string> blobNames = blobContainer.GetBlobs(prefix: "virtualfolder").Select(b => b.Name).ToList();
```